# CommonJS dependencies in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services

I'm using libraries in my Angular project which give me the following warning:

```
...depends on 'core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
```

I have already imported it into my angular.json with allowedCommonJsDependencies, but that got too big.
How would I use the ECMAScript modules in Order to do it like its supposed to.

This is my whole

```
 "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
          "lodash",
          "uuid",
          "url",
          "buffer",
          "ulid",
          "camelcase-keys",
          "@aws-crypto/sha256-browser",
          "@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-logs",
          "@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service",
          "@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-v2",
          "@aws-sdk/client-location",
          "@aws-sdk/eventstream-codec",
          "@aws-sdk/eventstream-marshaller",
          "isomorphic-unfetch",
          "js-cookie",
          "core-js/modules/es.array.index-of.js",
          "core-js/modules/es.array.iterator.js",
          "core-js/modules/es.array.reduce.js",
          "core-js/modules/es.array.reverse.js",
          "core-js/modules/es.promise.js",
          "core-js/modules/es.regexp.to-string.js",
          "core-js/modules/es.string.ends-with.js",
          "core-js/modules/es.string.includes.js",
          "core-js/modules/es.string.match.js",
          "core-js/modules/es.string.replace.js",
          "core-js/modules/es.string.split.js",
          "core-js/modules/es.string.starts-with.js",
          "core-js/modules/es.string.trim.js",
          "core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator.js",
          "raf",
          "rgbcolor",
          "cookie",
          "jspdf-autotable",
          "@aws-crypto/crc32",
          "@aws-crypto/crc32"
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```json
  "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [ "*" ]
```